# Fatal error code 401 when connecting to Cloud Datastore

Tags: php, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, credentials

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud Datastore, using the code below. I have tried to follow [these quidelines](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) as well as [these](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.105.0/datastore/datastoreclient). I am using Composer and my code is in a Wordpress plugin. I have put my credentials file in the same folder as the script and it is found.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/*
* Plugin Name: Cloud Datastore Connection
*/

add_shortcode( 'cd_connect', 'cloud_datastore_connection' );

use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;

function cloud_datastore_connection( $attributes )
{
// For Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Authenticate using keyfile data
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('/www/.../XXX.json'), true)
]);

$datastore = new DatastoreClient(['projectId' => 'ultunaphotons']);

// Create an entity
$bob = $datastore->entity('Person');
$bob['firstName'] = 'Bob';
$bob['email'] = 'bob@example.com';
$datastore->insert($bob);

// Update the entity
$bob['email'] = 'bobV2@example.com';
$datastore->update($bob);

// testing
print bob['email'];
}

?>
```

I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: {
>   "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required
>   authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie
>   or other valid authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
>   "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } in
>   /www/.../vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:362
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /www/.../vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php(206): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #1 /www/.../vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RestTrait.php(95):
>   Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
>   Ar in
>   /www/.../vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php
>   on line 362

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?